# How to yield a block in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view with this :

```
<%= render 'test' do %>
  test
<% end %>
```

And a partial like this :

```
<%= yield %>
```

When I go to the view, I want to see "test" but I see nothing.

Is there a way to yield a block inside a partial?

Comment: Pass it as a local parameter, maybe? (`render 'form', locals: {my_var: 'test'}`)

Comment: In the question, this is just an example, I have a larger form to pass and I think it will be uggly to pass it as a variable.

Comment: Look at `content_for`. It might suit your needs. However, it's the first time I hear of this content injection. Usually partials provide content for parent views, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify that given partial behaves as a layout:

```
<%= render layout: 'test' do %>
  test
<% end %>
```